# How do I make sure the user uses /'s?

Tags: python

```
elif search.lower() == "m":
    DMY = input("please enter your date of birth you are looking for (date/month/year) : ")
    DMY = DMY.split("/")
    DMY = DMY[1]

    for line in open("datafile.txt"):
        if DMY in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: use `re` or `datetime` module for validation

Comment: or simply `if not "/" in DMY: ...`...

Comment: The code should be re-styled to neatly separate the steps of input, validation and action: the 'elif' on first line tells me that you do all the steps in a single 'if' branch...

Comment: You shouldn’t require separation characters or some other arbitrary format. Let the user enter the date however they want and try your best to parse the correct date from it; only if you really can’t, throw an error and let them correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use exception handling:

```
DMY = input("please enter your date of birth you are looking for (date/month/year) :` ")
DMY = DMY.split("/", 2)
try:
    DMY = int(DMY[1])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    # User did not use (enough) slashes or the middle value was not an integer
    print("Oops, did you put in an actual date?")
```

or you could try and parse the date:

```
import datetime

DMY = input("please enter your date of birth you are looking for (date/month/year) :` ")
try:
    DMY = datetime.datetime.strptime(DMY, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
except ValueError:
    # User entered something that doesn't fit the pattern dd/mm/yyyy
    print("Oops, did you put in an actual date?")
```

The latter has the advantage that you now have an actual `datetime.date()` object, which does much more than just check that the user entered slashes and integer numbers; it also validates that the value entered can actually be interpreted as a date. `30/02/4321` would not parse because there is no 30th of February, even in the year 4321.

Comment: +1 The code is perfect, but I like to use a while loop to force the user to enter in the desired format. It is a good practice?

Comment: @Llopis: Yup, that's good practice. Use a `while True` loop, keep asking, until you have valid input. Then use `break` to end the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use find:

```
s = "29/01/2014"
if s.find("/") == -1:
    print "No '/' here!"
else:
    print "Found '/' in the string."
```